# How to work with redirection if http status is 200

Tags: vue.js

What is the best way to implement correct logic by using micro service.

for example this is login process if username/password is correct it redirect to home page. but if someone change the response or intercept the response it will also redirect to home how can we prevent this process ?

```
 async login(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      const response = await fetch("http://localhost:3000/login", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          username: this.username,
          password: this.password,
        }),
      });
      const { user, token } = await response.json();
      this.$router.push("/");
```

Comment: hey mate, You can look at [router navigation guards](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html)

Comment: wouldn't you be able to check the response for some information about it being "changed" or "intercepted" that you could then use to change how you redirect?

Comment: @yoduh can you elaborate how can we check ?

Comment: It's a very vague question, but you would just check the `response` object for whatever properties/values you know would be different.  You must have an idea about what conditions you expect to see for whether or not you redirect to your home page.  This being a login endpoint I assume there must be some message or status returned with the response object for "failed" or other non-successful logins.